# Will I run into problems if temporarily removing Uniqueness on Emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid, actionmailer

So I'm currently messing around with ActionMailer / SendGrid for the first time, trying to configure some emails being sent out from the app. It's all working ok so far, but the problem is that in my seed file I have a lot of fake users with fake email accounts. This is obviously not great as it messes with my SendGrid reputation when sending emails out to wrong addresses while I'm testing stuff out. For example, I tried to add Devise's ":confirmable" in, and suddenly upon running db:seed all my fake users were emailed

As a potential solution, I thought I'd temporarily allow emails to not be unique, and then have every user have the same email address (an actual one that I registered, so they will actually be delivered). So I went ahead and removed devise's ":validatable", and was about to do a migration to change the last part (changing true to false) on this index on the users table:

```
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
```

But after doing further research, I have come across opinions that say this will potentially mess stuff up once I want to change that back to the way it was.

What would YOU do to work around this? what is the best course of action here? I'd be happy about your feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scenarios like this I would keep the unique validation and have a single valid email address for testing purposes.

You can still generate unique email addresses using a + sign and follow with a unique identifier.

For clarity:

Create a valid email account such as mytestuser@gmail.com.

When you create your users assign them an email of mytestuser+uniquecode@gmail.com

Anything beyond and including the + sign is ignored for the sake of mail delivery so all messages will be sent to mytestuser@gmail.com, yet each of your users will still have a unique email address.

Comment: This of course only works if you use a GMail address as the destination! But certainly making sure that you own all the email addresses you might send to is a Good Idea.

Comment: Thanks guys, you've both ended several days of frustration for me! 

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is configuring SendGrid properly, you need to make sure you use real email addresses that you own. But I suspect your issue here is more about building and checking application logic and ActionMailer. I'd really advise against removing the constraint because that is bound to come back and bite you at some point.

What I do is to configure Rails to use a different mail service on local and dev instead of SendGrid (which I then enable only for the qa and live environments). This lets me use [MailTrap](https://mailtrap.io/) while I'm building the app and sending possibly-broken emails! MailTrap never sends emails to the specified address - it simply receives the emails your app sends and stores them in a single inbox that you can then check to see that your emails have been sent and what they look like, regardless of the specified recipient email address. (Other similar services are available: Mailinator is one.) This lets you use random email addresses while building, and thus retain your uniqueness constraint without sending email to random addresses.

To do this, set up the different mail configs in `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb`. (Test is set up as default, with emails in test mode and thus not going out to the real world anyway.)

Comment: Hey, thank you for this!! As I was using a gmail address the above solution worked like a charm for me. But this is just adding to the goodness - thanks so much!